# Extracting specific JSON field from .responseText to single excel cell

Tags: json, excel, vba, api, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve a particular field, resolve, from JSON. I am not sure as to how I can go about getting that one field. I added the Msgbox [Exists & Fail] to see if the code is able to read the word resolve within the cell, however i am returned with fail.

Is there any way i can get only the field resolve? Kindly assist.

Thank you!

```
 TargetURL = "https://api.passivetotal.org/v2/dns/passive?query=passivetotal.org"
    actionType = "Content-Type"
    actionWord = "application/json"
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", TargetURL, False
        .setRequestHeader actionType, actionWord
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic <Encoded 64>"
        .send
        If .Status = 200 Then
            Sheets(6).Cells(Count, 10).Value = "Connected"
            Debug.Print .responseText
            MsgBox .responseText
            Set JSON = ParseJson(.responseText)
            Sheets(6).Cells(Count, 8).Value = .responseText
            If Sheets(6).Cells(Count, 8).Value = ("resolve") Then
                MsgBox ("Exists")
            Else
                MsgBox ("Fail")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox .Status & ": " & .StatusText
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: When trying the code it throws unauthorized error. You may edit your post and put sample of JSON

Comment: I assume <Encoded 64> is your base64 encoded user + password string? Is this successfully hitting the API and the problem is simply with the accessing of an item in the JSON response? Or is the call failing?

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

### Parsing the JSON response:

The following reads in the results json from a file and parses out each resolve. It uses `JSONConverter.bas`. Note I have extracted the"results" JSON collection in my python script which would be the same as you doing  `json("results")` on the converted JSON string via    `Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("results")`.

After adding `JSONConverter.bas` to your project you need to go tools > references > Add reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetJSONExtract()
    Dim fso As Object, jsonFile As Object, jsonText As String, json As Object, item As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set jsonFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sample.json")
    jsonText = jsonFile.ReadAll
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)  '<== Using results collection
    'Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("results")  '<== In your vba XMLHTTP version
    For Each item In json
        Debug.Print item("resolve")
    Next
End Sub
```

As you were after how to parse the JSON that it was I have shown.

---

### Additional notes:

I actually used the python script shown below; adapted from the API documentation. I then added in a bit of code to write the response out to a JSON file for later import. Run using Anaconda/Spyder.

```
import requests
import json

username = 'xxx'
key = 'yyy'
auth = (username, key)
base_url = 'https://api.passivetotal.org'

def passivetotal_get(path, query):
    url = base_url + path
    data = {'query': query}
    response = requests.get(url, auth=auth, json=data)
    return response.json()

pdns_results = passivetotal_get('/v2/dns/passive', 'passivetotal.org')

for resolve in pdns_results['results']:
   print('Found resolution: {}'.format(resolve['resolve']))


with open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Output.json", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(json.dumps(pdns_results['results']))
```

That prints out all the resolves.

The original returned JSON structure looks like:

[image: structure]

The object returned is a collection of dictionaries. You access the required value by the dictionary key `"resolve"`

Comment: That's great. You are awesome. I think the loop would be through "results" `For Each item In json("results")` and item would be declared as Variant ..That worked for me in that way

Comment: @YasserKhalil I pulled out results collection when I used: pdns_results['results']  in python. So, I was already working with the necessary json. But yes, with vba you would want json("results") to generate the same json. I will edit to make clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I have no great idea about python. I have installed it but how can I test the code you have provided?

Comment: Do you have anaconda with spyder installed? You could also use jupyter notebook via anaconda/azure machine learning studio, or create a .py file and insert the script and call that from python/command line

Comment: I have installed before pycharm. Is that OK?

Comment: Sure. I haven't used it for a long time but create .py file in that IDE and run.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding me. I have got error at this line `import requests`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182106/discussion-between-qharr-and-yasserkhalil).