# XMLHTTP with Hash character

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to scrape a website with xmlhttp and VBA.

The Url has a hash(#) symbol  and is misinterpreted by VBA...

This is the same problem as explained here :
[Error in XMLHTTP Get request with Special character in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530577/error-in-xmlhttp-get-request-with-special-character-in-url)

The code is as follow :

```
Sub webscraping()
Dim x               As String
Dim req             As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim doc             As HTMLDocument

x = "https://search.gleif.org/#/search/"

Set req = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    With req
        .Open "GET", x, False
        .send
        If .Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox "Http Request Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can side step this by calling the API direct with your search term as shown below. I am using a [json parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to handle the json response. After adding the `.bas` at the link to your project, also go VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

Note there are queryString parameters you can alter here: `"&page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=15"`. This is currently with page=1 and records per page at 15.

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub webscraping()
    Dim url As String
    Dim req As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim json As Object
    Const TERM = "banana corp."

    url = "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records?filter%5Bfulltext%5D=" & Application.EncodeURL(TERM) & "&page%5Bnumber%5D=1&page%5Bsize%5D=15"

    Set req = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    With req
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        If .Status <> 200 Then
            MsgBox "Http Request Error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With
    Stop
    'Do something with json
End Sub
```

There is a lot of info returned so here is just an extract from it:

[image]

Research the API here:

https://www.gleif.org/en/lei-data/gleif-lei-look-up-api/access-the-api

Comment: Excellent of you @QHarr ! Sorry to interupt this thread, might I ask how you can extract information from the `Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)`. I did a `For Each item In Json` and used `Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("data")`, but is unable to get for example: `"legalName":{"name":` or `"status":"ACTIVE"`. Any idea where I can start? I have tried to follow one of your posts to [extract json field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866031/extracting-specific-json-field-from-responsetext-to-single-excel-cell) but with no luck:

Comment: Hi - I will post a pastebin later - just chase me this evening for it

Comment: Hi, you are too nice :)!. I have progressed a little bit. When I know the LEI code https://leilookup.gleif.org/api/v2/leirecords?lei=5299008TNNMXDKX6JB96, I use the following site to get the structure outlined: (http://json.parser.online.fr/) and then I use `Debug.Print item("Entity")("EntityStatus")("$")`. // Still trying to work with your code when I'm searching for the company name and want to retrieve the LEI code. Not sure how I should retrieve the `item` in a `For Each...` Loop then, since the structure seem more complex...

Comment: Exactly. HUGE thanks!!! Thanks to you I figured it out. 
So the code would be, given this [JSON structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSpVl.png), `Dim lei As String` // `lei = Json("data")(1)("attributes")("entity")("legalAddress")("country") 'Country` // `lei = Json("data")(1)("attributes")("entity")("status") 'Entity Status (Active/Not Active)` // `lei = Json("data")(1)("attributes")("entity")("legalName")("name") 'Legal name` // `lei = Json("data")(1)("attributes")("registration")("status")`.

Comment: well done. Bet you feel more comfortable reading json now :-)