# Print value from JSON object to excel sheet (Parse JSON to VBA)

Tags: json, excel, vba, api

I have for a long time used QHarr's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335501/xmlhttp-with-hash-character) to parse JSON by using a [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON).
Code used is: `Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)`

It have stopped working and it doesn't work for the following URL request `URL = "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records?filter[lei]=5493001ZDI5KQPZTPI85"`, so I have tried to use another method.

I'm trying to retrieve the legal name as an exampel:

[image]

It seems like I get a JSON object in return but I'm struggle with how I can print the values to the excel sheet. I thought this method would do the trick as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360440/how-to-parse-json-with-vba-without-external-libraries) by July Tech:

```
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = json("data")(0)("attributes")("legalName")("name")  'Entity Status (Active/Not Active)
```

But I only get error 438:

[image]

**Full Code:**

```
Sub getData()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Set the outputdata sheet

Dim json As Object
Dim item As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim scriptControl As Object

Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
scriptControl.Language = "JScript"

URL = "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records?filter[lei]=5493001ZDI5KQPZTPI85"

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    Set json = scriptControl.Eval("(" + .responseText + ")")
    'MsgBox scriptControl.Eval("(" + .responseText + ").data.attributes.lei")
    .abort
End With



Dim jsent As Variant
ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = json("data")(0)("attributes")("legalName")("name")  'Entity LegalName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing "entity" from your path:

```vb
Dim json As Object

Set json = ParseJson(Range("a1").Value) 'loading json from a cell for testing...

Debug.Print json("data")(1)("attributes")("entity")("legalName")("name") 'BREVAN HOWARD MASTER FUND LIMITED
```

FYI it's super-unsafe to use the Scriptcontrol to parse JSON from any site you don't control.  That script control instance isn't running in a browser sandbox, so any js you execute inside it could spin up (eg) a new Scripting.Filesystemobject and start deleting your files.

For completeness though:

```vb
Dim scriptControl, json

Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
scriptControl.Language = "JScript"

Debug.Print scriptControl.Eval("(" + Range("A1").Value + ")['data'][0]['attributes']['entity']['legalName']['name']")
```

Comment: Thanks!! Getting blind on this. I wanted to avoid it too, but started to get desperate. I have issues with using ParsJson but got it to work somehow now with the JSON parser! Thanks for taking your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the extra completeness. Always interesting to see the answer and learn more/new things. Gives a a better understanding. And a + plus for highlighting the drawback :)

Answer (score 0):

Working code, thanks to Tim Williams:

```
Sub getData()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Set the outputdata sheet

Dim json As Object
Dim item As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim scriptControl As Object

Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
scriptControl.Language = "JScript"

URL = "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records?filter[lei]=5493001ZDI5KQPZTPI85"

Dim rslt As String

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    rslt = .responseText
    Debug.Print rslt
End With

Set json = ParseJson(rslt) 'loading json from a cell for testing...

Debug.Print json("data")(1)("attributes")("entity")("legalName")("name")  'Entity Status (Active/Not Active)
End Sub
```